# Active_admin error on #new and #edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have an error on trying to access to #new or #edit action on the hosting. At my computer everything work fine.

```
Started GET "/admin/operations/new" for 109.167.192.252 at 2012-09-27 15:45:37 +0400
Processing by Admin::OperationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered /home/z/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-e42acc0501ee/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb (43.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 53ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `call' for :silence:Symbol):
    1: insert_tag renderer_for(:new)
  app/admin/operations.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This error get at any model registered in active_admin. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something bad with f.buttons , just use f.actions insted.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like an issue with papperclip gem, try to add *:required => false* to your papperclips inputs

```
 e.g.
 f.input :photo, :required => false.....
```

*regards!*